# Submodules: git status vs git checkout - untracked files

Tags: git, git-submodules, branching-and-merging

I have a GitHub fork which is cloned on my laptop.

I also have PR which I am trying to fix.

So what I did is:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout <my_pr_branch>
```

At this point I got a failure due to a bunch of unmerged files in one of the Git submodules that was updated in the meantime.

But if I after that do `git status` - I will not see the untracked files.

Now at this point I could remove those files from my local repo and update the branch. But I prefer to keep my master in sync.

How do I properly update the master and then switch to my PR branch?

Comment: I don't understand your situation. Can you share the output of each command?

Comment: If you need to update your PR branch, either merge master in it or rebase it on master. Also keep in mind that your fork might not be automatically sync with the upstream original repo, it's unclear if you're working only on your fork or want to push stuff to the original repo.

Comment: @GaëlJ, `git status` shows the submodule as being having new stuff, but it doesn't show the new files in the output. Should I just do `git add . && git commit -m "Update to latest code"`? and then switch to my PR branch?

Comment: Oh, you are using Git submodules. This was not obvious at first. Forget my moments above then. I don't know nothing about submodules and the way they work!

Comment: @GaëlJ, `At this point I got a failure due to a bunch of unmerged files in one of the Git submodules that was updated in the meantime.` - weird you said that it was not clear. And I also tagged the question with the `git-submodules`... ;-)

Comment: Do you mean that you got a failure from one of the git commands, or when building/running your application using the updated code?

Comment: @mkrieger1, I meant - running `git checkout <my_PR_branch>` failed because the submodule was updated and now it says `Untracked files will be overwritten by checkout`

Comment: Then you should either remove or commit the untracked files first.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I can just do `git add. && git commit`, right? From my main project directory?

Comment: From the directory where the untracked files are. I don't know if it's in the main repository or in the submodule.